# How to restore cursor shape when exiting/stopping vim?

Tags: cursor

I have this in my `.vimrc`

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>[5 q"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>[3 q"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>[2 q"
```

The problem is that I keep the block cursor shape when I exit vim. How can I easily restore the previous cursor shape when I quit or I stop vim?

Comment: Is your terminal's default cursor shape a vertical bar?